# Does the Yoast news plugin require Google News approval?

Tags: yoast, google-news

I have Google News approved Tech Website, in the Google News Publisher it shows the listing as "LIVE". But my website and its contents aren't showing in the Google News tab, hence no traffic at all. Meanwhile, my website is ranking very solid on Google web search, but not on Google News.

Do I need to get my site approved by Google before it shows up in Google News from the data provided by the Yoast plugin?